# How to filter out NULL elements of tibble's list column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a tibble like below:

```
structure(list(id = 1:11, var1 = c("A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "B"), var2 = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, structure(list(
    x = c(0, 1, 23, 3), y = c(0.75149005651474, 0.149892757181078, 
    0.695984086720273, 0.0247649133671075)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'd like to leave only the rows where `var2` is NOT null. But the simple `!is.null()` just doesn't work. `df %>% filter(!is.null(var2))` returns the whole `df`. Why is that and how can I filter out all those rows with `NULL` in `var2` column?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One possibility also involving `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 filter(!map_lgl(var2, is.null))

     id var1  var2            
  <int> <chr> <list>          
1     4 B     <tibble [4 × 2]>
```

Reflecting the properties of `is.null()`, you can also do:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 filter(!is.null(var2))
```

Comment: It's neat, I like it!

Answer (score 5):

`!is.null()` doesnt work because your `var2` is a nested list (list of lists). It contains a tibble as its fourth element. A `tibble` is a list beacuse it is a `data.frame` and `is.null` checks only the first level of the nested list.

```
#show that the tibble is a list:
> is.list(df$var2[[4]])
[1] TRUE
```

You can try filtering on `lengths(df$var2) > 0`

```
> lengths(df$var2)
 [1] 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
# each of the columns of the tibble in var2[[4]] is one element 
# of the list contained in var2[[4]]. Thus var2[[4]] is a list of length two

> df %>% filter(lengths(var2) > 0)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     id var1  var2            
  <int> <chr> <list>          
1     4 B     <tibble [4 x 2]>
>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did some explaration and the issue is that `is.null()`, by contrast to eg. `is.na()` is not vectorised (this is actually paraphrasing your answer, but I leave it here as potentially helpful to get what you mean).

Comment: @jakes it turns ot that NULL is not a vector and is dropped on concatenation : ```is.vector(c(NULL, NULL))``` returns ```FALSE```, hence there is nothing to vectorize. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 5):

The function `drop_na()` from `tidyr` will also work for `NULL`. You just have to be careful for the edge case where you have both `NULL` and `NA` values and only wanted to drop the `NULL` for some reason.

> Drop rows containing missing values

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  drop_na(var2)

#        id var1  var2                
#     <int> <chr> <list>              
#   1     4 B     <tibble[,2] [4 x 2]>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I have encountered that problem multiple times, and this is the first time I have found this straight forward answer.  Seriously, big thanks!

Comment: I think it is important to note though that if there are different classes assigned to the object then those classes will get dropped